# vscode Extension - Decoration for Font color

Tags: python, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am writing on a vscode extension.

It is an extension for Python files, and a DSL which gets triggered by "### " at the beginning of lines.

At the moment I am highlighting these lines with:

```
const myTextDecorator1 = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
      backgroundColor: "#a6ff001f",
      borderWidth: '1px',
      borderStyle: 'solid',
      borderColor: '#a6ff001f'
    });
```

Now i also want to Highlight the DSLs Syntax. Is there a way to change the font color? I didn't find a possibility to do it.

Comment: you have the `color` attribute of the properties object

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I tried it before but it didn't work, so i thought it doesn't work together with the python syntax highlighter. But it worked now so I did sth wrong ...